# Selenium not moving to next webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

in my code when we click an button a new tab will be open then we have to select the option. However selenium is not working on the new tab, I have used switch to option but no option.
i am attaching the code below. Please check

public class trail {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException { 
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://orgd8994c71.crm8.dynamics.com/main.aspx?appid=e474bdc4-6835-ed11-9db1-002248d5d2d5&pagetype=entityrecord&etn=opportunity&id=818c1b86-0565-4021-9b82-cd67fac340a9");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //maximize window screen
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //user id
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']"));
        username.sendKeys("gokul87141@gmail.com");
        //user id button
        WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")); next.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='i0118']"));
        password.sendKeys("Youaregreat!@#");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //password button
        WebElement next1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")); next1.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //next button
        WebElement next2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='idSIButton9']")); next2.click();
        Thread.sleep(22000);
      //click button
         WebElement next21 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"opportunity|NoRelationship|Form|new.opportunity.Command0.Command10-button\"]/span/span[2]")); next21.click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        //switch to option
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        
        //second click button
         WebElement next22 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")); next22.click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));       
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a second window created ? Moreover, are you sure about the order of the windows in your ArrayList ?

Answer (score 0):

@gokulkrishna

First of all -- not sure; but if your email and password is legit in your question, you should remove them ASAP!

What I am seeing is that you are getting the window handles before you make the click. Since you are doing the 'click' after you gather the window handles, there is only 1 available. The current page you are on.

It should work fine once you put 'click' before:

```
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
```

Thann tabs will get all the handles available and you can do your switch.